# How do I combine Result and State in Elm?

Tags: haskell, monads, elm, monad-transformers

I am struggling with Elm's lack of monads. A library implementing the state monad for Elm (http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/folkertdev/elm-state/latest/State) has helped me quite a bit.

The problem is that I have now run into a situation where I have alternately nested Result and State types, when I only want to have one of each.

I tried to write a function with the following signature, but it seems impossible, because the inner Result is only known once the outer State is evaluated.

```
join : Result a (State s (Result a (State s x))) -> Result a (State s x)
```

Maybe it would work if I put the Result inside the State in the return value, but that would generate a dummy State in case the outer Result is `Err`.

I think the right idea would be to make something that is both Result and State. Can someone who is familiar with Haskell monad transformers explain how they solve this kind of problem or suggest an alternative solution?

Here is a rough version of one place where the problem arises:

```
  generateConstraints environment value
  |> Result.map (State.map (\(value, valueC) ->
    Result.map
      (State.map2 (\this (body, bodyC) ->
        ( this
        , valueC ++ bodyC ++ [(this, body)]
        ))
      freshTypevar)
      (generateConstraints (extend environment name value) body))
  )
```

Comment: Monad transformers are kind of a pain when you mix the same type of transformer. I typically use monad typeclasses, but those fail when the type appears multiple times. A solution for that is newtyping the particular contexts you need.

Comment: I don't really need to have the same monad multiple times. The code snippet that I included is one case of `generateConstraints`, which returns `Result String (State Int (Type, List Constraint))`. Recursion works fine, but there is something different with the constraint generation for let bindings that messes up the monads.

Comment: I still don't know how to combine having state and possibly being erroneous, but the particular example I gave miraculously solved itself because I was able to move all exceptional results out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a monad that is both. I had to sacrifice the ability to fail before State is touched, because I need to be able to fail after.

```
type alias Infer a = State Int (Result String a)

infer : a -> Infer a
infer x =
  State.state (Ok x)

map : (a -> value) -> Infer a -> Infer value
map f x =
  State.map (Result.map f) x

andThen : (a -> Infer b) -> Infer a -> Infer b
andThen f x =
  State.andThen
    (\r -> case r of
      Ok v -> f v
      Err e -> State.state <| Err e
    )
    x

andMap : Infer y -> Infer (y -> z) -> Infer z
andMap y =
  andThen (\g -> map g y)

map2 : (a -> b -> c) -> Infer a -> Infer b -> Infer c
map2 f x y =
  map f x
  |> andMap y

map3 : (a -> b -> c -> d) -> Infer a -> Infer b -> Infer c -> Infer d
map3 f a b c =
  map2 f a b
  |> andMap c

map4 : (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> Infer a -> Infer b -> Infer c -> Infer d -> Infer e
map4 f a b c d =
  map3 f a b c
  |> andMap d
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone who is familiar with Haskell monad transformers explain how they solve this kind of problem or suggest an alternative solution?

Well, I can at least try. This is how your type looks directly translated to Haskell:

```
type EffM a s x = Either a (State s x)
```

A rather obvious observation is that it's not a monad transformer.<sup>2</sup> That's how a transformer would look like:

```
type TransM a s x = EitherT a (State s) x
```

As you can see, the only change is the `T` and the fact that `x` is outside the parens. The latter part is essential in understanding the transformer approach.

The core idea is that the `State` is a part of the result production regardless of whether the `Either` results in "success" or "fail", whereas in your case producing "fail" means the state operation is never touched. I'd need to think harder what that means in practice, but intuitively the transformer approach is what you're gonna have in mind when working with typical, imperative code.

Now, when you use such a transformer, `join` is actually provided for free, as a consequence of fitting into the Monad interface.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Control.Monad

type Eff e s a = EitherT e (State s) a

-- type the following in REPL

λ :t join
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a

λ :t join :: Eff e s (Eff e s a) -> Eff e s a
join :: Eff e s (Eff e s a) -> Eff e s a
     :: Eff e s (Eff e s a) -> Eff e s a

-- the slightly cryptic output above means that it typechecks correctly
```

So this is how Haskell<sup>1</sup> solves it. Now, it's obviously possible to write a specialized `EitherState` type this way (altough I'd personally flip those two in all of the examples to `StateEither` - feels more natural), mirroring what the implementation of `join` for respective transformers would do. I don't know if writing `EitherT` specifically is possible in Elm.

---

<sup>1</sup> One possible approach. There are other, recursion schemes/Free probably being the one to watch in the upcoming years. The inherent ordering of effects stacking turns out to be more problematic than it initially seems.

<sup>2</sup> It's also not a `Monad`, at least in the sense that the `x` can't be the direct type in the Monad instance (because `Either` can obviously act as one in the specialized case).

Comment: You were a bit too slow; I already solved the issue myself. Would EitherT State work in my case? At least the way I wrote it, it only works the other way round.

Comment: `join` comes for free because it is pretty much the same as `>>=`, right? Also, in my andThen there is the very ugly `Err e -> State.state <| Err e`. I think at least in Elm it has to be done that way because `Err e -> x` does not typecheck.

Comment: @Joonazan I saw your comment, but figured I might answer anyway. I think it would work in your case; the order of those transformers shouldn't matter. And yes, `join` is simply `join x = x >>= id`. The "ugliness" of your implementation comes mostly from the fact that you have to unwrap both layers at the same time, while transformers can split it up and allow composition later.

Comment: Can you elaborate? My interpretation is that if I have a Result State, then the value of the Result can not depend on State. Yet it has to, because to implement type inference for `let`, I have to extend the environment with the type of the declared value before inferring the body of the let.

Comment: @Joonazan when you have a `ResultT State` or `StateT Result`, you can effectively write in *both* at the same time. The core idea is that you only produce the value once, the only difference is how you access the context functions (`lift`, `liftIO`, mtl typeclasses...)